# Alert message wont work

Tags: javascript

### html embedded with javascript

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <script type ="text/javascript">
```

have I called this function correctly????

```
function displayatts()
{
    document.getElementById("buttonone").onclick = saysomething;

}
```

is there something wrong here???

```
function saysomething()
{
    alert("I am 28 years old");
}
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" id="buttonone" value="me" >

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your tags are messed up. Close the `<HEAD>` before you open the `<BODY>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is the full example.

This will work for sure. 
Test it if you want. 
Copy and paste the below code into W3Schools test environment, "Edit and Click me" to test.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type ="text/javascript">

    function saysomething()
    {
        alert("I am 29 years old");
    }

    function displayatts()
    {
        document.getElementById("buttonone").onclick = saysomething;

    }

</script>


<body onload="displayatts();">
 <input type="button" id="buttonone" value="me" >
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs before the document is parsed.
Therefore, `getElementById` returns null.

Move the `<script>` to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

> *"have I called this function correctly????"*

You haven't called the `displayatts()` function at all. Add the following to the end of your script:

```
window.onload = displayatts;
```

That way `displayatts()` will be called automatically once the page finishes loading. It will, in turn, setup the click handler on your button.

Also, include the closing `</head>` tag just before the opening `<body>` tag.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/rxDXa/

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload  =  displayatts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code before `</body>` tag in your page.So you can be sure if element is null or not or the code is try to work before your html element is rendered.
Hope this helps your situation..

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("buttonone");
if(element){
element.setAttribute("onclick", "saysomething();");
}else
{
alert("element null, move the code to bottom or check element exists");
}
</script>
```